# Android permission reduces the number of supported devices

Tags: android, android-permissions, google-play

I m up loading my latest apk onto google play store with few new permissions

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

doing so have reduced the number of supported devices. How can I make it support the earlier devices as it did before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you can use `<uses-feature>` tag in your manifest file to tell google play that your app doesn't need the proper hardware for that if the device doesn't support that hardware:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="false" />
```